Pitch accent of numbers with 万
I know that for the numbers 1-10, 万 changes the pitch accent to fall on the first mora of 万 (i.e. 一万(イチマ'ン), 五万(ゴマ'ン), 十万(ジューマ'ン)).
But what about for words like 二十万, 十五万, 三百万. Do 二十, 十五, and 三百 keep their own pitch accent, and 万 retains its own, or do they lose their original pitch with down-step on the 万?

万 is a little special. Every (technically except one) possible combination with 万 in a single accent phrase puts accent on 万's first mora. Namely, this comprises [一～十九; 二十, 三十, ..., 九十; 百, 二百, ..., 九百; （一）千, 二千, ..., 九千] + 万.
The only exception is 15. Prescriptively, 十五 is じゅうご【HLLL】 so that 十五万 is じゅうごまん【HLLLLL】. However, じゅうご【LLHH】 is far more popular in speech and thus derives じゅうごまん【LLHHHL】 which eliminates the exception.
The reason why 万 is special because higher powers of 104 suffixes (億, 兆, 京...) do not behave like 万 but always put accent before them (if the position is 特殊拍, one more backward): いちおく【LHLL】, じゅうおく【HHLLL】, さんびゃくおく【LHHHHLL】 etc.
